# Looking for Add Title Tag on Feature Images on WP

Tags: post-thumbnails, title

I am facing problem with adding title tag on feature images and also thumbnail posts. I tried to find out but not successful to resolve these kinds of issues. Kindly help me please how to add title image tag on feature images on Wordpress.

Answer (score 2):

when you upload image to WordPress you must to fill Title field. and also your theme must use default WordPress thumbnail function.